# UITableView selected row in the middle of frame

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipickerview

I need to have the possibility to put the selected line on the middle of frame. So if I select the first or the last row, this row needs to be on the center and not clipped to the top (or to the bottom) of the tableview (something like an `UIPickerView`).

This is my code on `scrollViewWillEndDragging`:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {

    CGFloat rowHeight = [delegate rowHeightForMyPickerView:self];
    CGFloat floatVal = targetContentOffset->y / rowHeight;
    NSInteger rounded = (NSInteger)(lround(floatVal));
    targetContentOffset->y = rounded * rowHeight;
    NSLog(@"Offset: %f Float: %f Row: %d",targetContentOffset->y,floatVal,rounded);
    [delegate myPickerView:self isOverRow:rounded];
}
```

With this code, I create snap effect but `rounded` is not the correct row. Changing the first and last cell height with a double height makes the problem disappear but I don't like that solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `UITableView` class can scroll to the selected `indexPath`, with animations as well, using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated` method. Preferably in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` method, add:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES]; //scrolls the selected cell to middle
}
```

Comment: is not what I need, for example if I have 3 visible row, I need to put the first row (index=0) in the second position, so: one blank space, row0,row1 the same for the last row where I need: last rowt-1,last row,blank space